# URL.getInputStream() causes java.security.cert.CertificateException: No subject alternative DNS name

Tags: java, https, inputstream

I have some code that sends out an email and reads the content from a template file.

Everything works fine until I use HTTPS. In this case an exception is thrown:

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: 
java.security.cert.CertificateException: No subject alternative DNS name matching lonlinux01 found.
at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:192) [jsse.jar:1.7.0_40]
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(SSLSocketImpl.java:1884) [jsse.jar:1.7.0_40]
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:276) [jsse.jar:1.7.0_40]
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:270) [jsse.jar:1.7.0_40]
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1341) [jsse.jar:1.7.0_40]
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(ClientHandshaker.java:153) [jsse.jar:1.7.0_40]
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Handshaker.java:868) [jsse.jar:1.7.0_40]
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Handshaker.java:804) [jsse.jar:1.7.0_40]
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1016) [jsse.jar:1.7.0_40]
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1312) [jsse.jar:1.7.0_40]
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1339) [jsse.jar:1.7.0_40]
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1323) [jsse.jar:1.7.0_40]
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(HttpsClient.java:563) [rt.jar:1.7.0_40]
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:185) [rt.jar:1.7.0_40]
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1300) [rt.jar:1.7.0_40]
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:254) [rt.jar:1.7.0_40]
    at com.cerillion.wsc.workers.EmailWorker.getEmailTemplateFile(EmailWorker.java:99) [classes:]
    ...
```

the code

```
url = new URL(templateurl);
urlConnection = url.openConnection();

urlConnection.setConnectTimeout(connectionTimeout);
urlConnection.setReadTimeout(connectionTimeout);
BufferedReader breader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(urlConnection.getInputStream()));
```

fails on **urlConnection.getInputStream()**

The rest of the application seems to work fine on HTTPS.

Comment: Is the host part of templateurl "lonlinux01", i.e. a not fully qualified name?  If so, try using the fully qualified name (including domain part).

Answer (score 2):

The TLS client cannot find the (fully qualified) server name in the certificate.

It looks like you're connecting to the server `lonlinux01` but the given server certificate has neither the common name `lonlinux01` nor a subject alternative name...

So adjust either your connection string with the fully qualified server name (to match the name from the certificate) or ask the server administrator to adjust his certificate (to match the fully qualified server name)

Comment: If that is the issue, why can I access the application?

Comment: @algiogia I don't know how you access *your application*... I don't know which server names are you using, which is the name of the template on which server... To say it easy: My crystal ball is out of order...

Comment: I access the application on https//lonlinux01/appName. The template file is in the WebContent folder, so I access it through https://lonlinux01/appName/templateFolder/templateName.html